# Can dependencies be added to scalafiddle?

Tags: scala

Using scalafiddle http://scalafiddle.net/console can I add a dependency to use within the fiddle, for example scalacheck ? Or are fiddles constraint by using just scala api ?

Comment: Try http://scastie.org/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://scalafiddle.io/ instead. 
It has a hard coded list of available dependencies here: https://github.com/scalafiddle/scalafiddle-editor/blob/master/server/src/main/resources/libraries.json (where you could try adding something as pull request if you need anything).